# How to transform string "lat, lon" into a POINT in MySql

Tags: mysql, spatial

I have latlon data stored in a single varchar as e.g. "51.51087974,-0.11101941" and I want to transform it into a POINT spatial value.  When the values are in separate floats I can use e.g. 
`UPDATE myTable SET coords = GeometryFromText( CONCAT( 'POINT(', lon, ' ', lat, ')' ) );`
and I can obviously replace the comma in my value with a space to get the POINT data, but lat and lon are then the wrong way around.  I'm sure this must be a common operation, but for the life of me cannot seem to find the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql's [substring_index()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to parse your coordinates data:

> Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the
>   delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of the
>   final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is
>   negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting
>   from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a
>   case-sensitive match when searching for delim.

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET coords = GeometryFromText( CONCAT( 'POINT(', substring_index(coord_field, ',',-1), ' ', substring_index(coord_field, ',',1), ')' ) );
```